# I need a better way to query an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, json, httparty

I have a t-shirt app that is linking with scalable press api. I have a solution that works, but there has to be a better way. The api has products with an array of colors, colors has an array of images. I want to display the image for the "Front", but the first image in the array isn't always the front. I am suffering from narrow vision because i can't think of a solution to query the array for the label "Front" better than this....

View:

```
<% if @product['colors'][0]['images'][0]['label'] =='Front' %>
  <%= image_tag @product['colors'][0]['images'][0]['url'] %>
<% elsif @product['colors'][0]['images'][1]['label'] =='Front' %>
  <%= image_tag @product['colors'][0]['images'][1]['url'] %>
<% elsif @product['colors'][0]['images'][2]['label'] =='Front' %>
  <%= image_tag @product['colors'][0]['images'][2]['url'] %>
<% elsif @product['colors'][0]['images'][3]['label'] =='Front' %>
  <%= image_tag @product['colors'][0]['images'][3]['url'] %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def show_product
  @product = scalable_press.show_product(params[:product])
end
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: When I see code like that, there is only one question to ask: how did you end up with that data-structure? What is `@product`, why whatever `colours` property contains has an image property?

Comment: He said, it was because of an API. Sometimes you don't have control over what's returned,

Comment: @Leito - Missed that part. I agree you don't have control over what's returned, but you have control over what you do with it. If that comes from json, it is easy enough to create a class responsible for translating json into an usable object. Then the code above would just read `@product.colors.first.front_image_url` without any unnecessary conditions, all classified and easy to read.

Comment: Yeah I don't have control of what is returned by the api. I hate it, but for some reason I can't come up with a better solution. There are 4 images per color, Front, Back, Left Sleeve, and Right sleeve. The images array has URL and Label. Their API is a bit sloppy i've come to find out, but they print my shirts with awesome quality and its starting to take me too long to input the order manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `find`:

```
<% item = @product['colors'][0]['images'].find{|i| i['label'] == 'Front'} %>
<%= image_tag item['url'] if item.present? %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time I have to deal with data structure I don't control I create a class to wrap that data structure into my own liking. The biggest issue I see above is that you link the API structure with your view, just imagine refactoring it once the API changes.

```
module <ExternalAPIName>
  IMAGE_TYPES = {
    front: "Front"
    ...
  }
  class Product
    attr_reader :colors

    def self.get(product)
      # Depending on what scalable_press is you can either call it directly or declare module attribute
      new scalable_press.show_product(product)
    end

    def initialize(data_hash)
      parse_colors(data_hash['colors'])
    end

    private

    def parse_colors(colors)
      @colors = colors.map {|color_hash| Color.new(color_hash) }
    end
  end

  class Color

    def initialize(color_hash)
      parse_images color_hash['images']
    end

    IMAGE_TYPES.each do |name, label|
      define_method "#{name}_image" do
        @images.find {|image| image.type == name }
      end
    end 

    private

    def parse_images(images)
      @images = images.map {|image_hash| Image.new(image_hash) }
    end
  end

  class Image
    attr_reader :url, :type

    def initialize(data_hash)
      @url = data_hash['url']
      @type = IMAGE_TYPES.key(data_hash['label'])
    end
  end
end
```

Quite a lot of code, I agree, but it largely simplifies the rest of your code:

controller:

```
@product = ExternalAPIName.get(params[:product])
```

View:

```
<%= image_tag(@product.colors.first.front_image.url) %>
```

It gives you full customisation power over the data your received and what is the most important, you converted the nested hash structure into objects which belongs to your application domain. You can now hook any filtering, searching and data manipulation methods into those objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a convenient map:

```
image_map = @product['colors'][0]['images'].each_with_object({}) do |h,obj| 
  obj[h["label"]] = h["url"]
ebd
```

Now, you can access various images URLs:

```
image_map["Right"]
#=> "http://i1.ooshirts.com/images/lab_shirts/Kiwi-5-R.jpg"

image_map["Left"]
#=> "http://i1.ooshirts.com/images/lab_shirts/Kiwi-5-L.jpg"
```

I am using the example JSON from [here](https://scalablepress.com/docs/#list-product-information), you should ideally add a link to it in question.